# Using dojo how do I correctly capture touch events on mobile devices?

Tags: web-applications, mobile, dojo

I have a dojox.mobile.valuepicker embedded on a simple webpage. The valuepicker works fine on any desktop browser but on an iPad or Android tablet it exhibits some strange behavior in the browser. If your increasing or decreasing the value on the iPad with the + and - buttons the value returned from the widget is always 1 greater or 1 less than than the value displayed in the valuepicker (if your increasing the value returned by the widget is 1 less than the value the widget displays, decreasing it's one more). I have tried this on multiple iPads with different OS versions. Here's my code.

```
 var widgetValueIs = null; 
                    widgetToTest= dijit.byId("rateMeasurement"); 
                    widgetToTest.on("touchend, click, change", function() { 
                        widgetValueIs = dijit.byId('rateMeasurement').get('value'); 
                        if (widgetValueIs >= 12 && widgetValueIs <= 20){ 
                         domAttr.set("rateScore", "innerHTML", widgetValue); 
                        } else if (widgetValueIs >= 9 && widgetValueIs <= 11){ 
                         domAttr.set("rateScore", "innerHTML", widgetValue); 

                        } else { 
                         domAttr.set("rateScore", "innerHTML", widgetValue); 
                        } 
                     });
```

I assuming this is something to do with my capture happening before the picker value is updated but how do I insure the value is retrieved **after** an update?

Thanks, 
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK from what I've been able to piece together it appears Dojo touch event handling has a delay mechanism built in it (to handle double touch and zoom type gestures). So to insure I am getting the correct value back from an updated widget I've run a small delay (250ms) after the touch event is fired. This now gets the correct value back from the dojox mobile widget.

```
'var widgetValueIs = null; 
                widgetToTest= dijit.byId("rateMeasurement"); 
                widgetToTest.on("touchend, click, change", function() { 
                // Add a delay to compensate for Dojo's touch event handling 
                   setTimeout(function() {
                    widgetValueIs = dijit.byId('rateMeasurement').get('value'); 
                    if (widgetValueIs >= 12 && widgetValueIs <= 20){ 
                     domAttr.set("rateScore", "innerHTML", widgetValue); 
                    } else if (widgetValueIs >= 9 && widgetValueIs <= 11){ 
                     domAttr.set("rateScore", "innerHTML", widgetValue); 

                    } else { 
                     domAttr.set("rateScore", "innerHTML", widgetValue); 
                    } 
                   }, 250);
                 }); '
```

**It appears I need the delay because I have some processing that executes on widget values immediately after a widget touch event is fired.** The above works for me however I'm sure if there is some funky Dojo way of handling this.